# How do I force nested list items to be the same width as parent list item?

Tags: css, list, nested, width

I have a horizontal parent list. Some of the list items display a nested vertical list when clicked. How do I force the items in the vertical sub list to be the same width as the parent list item?

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BXnxc/1/).

[image]

HTML:

```
<ul class="mainMenu horizontalMenu bulletless fullWidth bold">
    <li class="showSubMenu">
        <div>Resumes &amp; Cover Letters &#x25BE; </div>
        <ul class="mainSubMenu bulletless">
            <li><a>Resumes</a></li>
            <li><a>Cover Letters</a></li>
            <li><a>Interviews</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li><li><a>Other Link</a>
    </li><li><a>Other Link</a></li>
 </ul>​
```

CSS:

```
.horizontalMenu li{    
    display: inline-block;
}
.mainMenu > li{
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.mainMenu a, .mainMenu div{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px;

}
.mainSubMenu{
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: +1 - Great job asking the question!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did the change on your fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/BXnxc/2/

The parent li needs to have `position:relative;` and the nested submenu has to have `width:100%;` and `position:absolute;`

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by specifying the parent `LI` as relative and child `UL` with `width: 100%`

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BXnxc/3/

```
.horizontalMenu li {    
    position: relative;
}
.horizontalMenu li ul {    
    width: 100%;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this by inheriting the width of the containing structures.  I set your mainMenu div to width of 200px and then width:inherit for the mainSubMenu.

http://jsfiddle.net/BXnxc/4/

```
.mainMenu a, .mainMenu div{
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 20px; 
    width:200px;
}
.mainSubMenu{
    position: absolute;
    width:inherit;
}

.mainSubMenu li
{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid grey; 
    width:inherit; 
}
```