# Forcing li elements to inherit the full width of their containers

Tags: html, css, snap.svg

I'm trying to force the li/a elements in this example to take the full width of the svg-snap animated menu you can see here...

http://tympanus.net/Development/ElasticSVGElements/dropdown.html

My latest attempt being here...

http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/KdypYL

The current issue is simply that the li/a elements are starting indented from the left of the parent ul element - meaning if you hover slightly to the left of the expanded menu text, you'll get no hover effect (i.e. the text won't change colour).

I've been playing around with suggestions from various other posts I've found (e.g. [How do I force nested list items to be the same width as parent list item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14145404/how-do-i-force-nested-list-items-to-be-the-same-width-as-parent-list-item)) but nothing has given the desired effect so far.

The only significant changes I've made to the original were to add these lines to ".menu__inner {"

```
float:left;
width: 100%;
position: relative;
```

Which at least ensures that the li elements have the correct width.   So now I'm just trying to figure out what css attribute will allow me to offset the elements to the left by the correct amount - any ideas are hugely appreciated!

Comment: can't you remove the padding of the UL and add it to the LIs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `float:left;` from `.menu__inner` and add a padding of 1-5px or whatever you see fit.

Your code:

```
.menu__inner {
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    float:left;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
```

The edited code:

```
.menu__inner {
    list-style:none;
    padding-left:5px; /* added a padding */
    font-size: 1.3em;
    margin: 0;
    /* removed float:left */
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 0;
    -webkit-transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
    transition: height 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.3, 1);
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: that worked perfectly thanks!  Apparently need to wait 4 minutes to accept the answer though!

Comment: You're totally welcome, good luck on the development! the menu looks nice already @d3wannabe (don't forget to accept )

Answer (score 1):

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/meqeeL

All I've done is added the following CSS:

```
ul.menu__inner{
  padding-left:0;
}

ul.menu__inner li a{
  padding-left:40px;
}
```

This removes the padding from the parent `ul` and applies it to the child `li a`.

This issue was due to the parent `ul` including a default `padding` and pushing the `a` link hover zone to the right.

By removing the padding on the `ul` and applying it to the actual link instead, the hover zone now expands to include the padding area as well as the link itself.

Comment: also works great - thanks Alvin - especially like the way the text is maintained in its original position

Comment: @d3wannabe - No problem, hope it helps.